# What effect does this if statement have on the time complexity of these nested loops?

Tags: c, performance, time-complexity

I have here 2 programs that desperately need an efficiency evaluation using the big o notation. For the first one, I'm unsure of the effect of the if statement. This one has a nested loop and they usually have efficiency O(n^2), but I can't be sure. The other one also has the nested loop but with a break; command.

```
/* modifies a so that all the even numbers appear before
all of the odd numbers. there are multiple possible results
-the order of the even numbers does not matter
-the order of the odd numbers does not matter
*/

void even_first(int a[], int len) {
  int temp = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
    if (a[i] % 2 == 0) {
      temp = a[i];
      for (int j = i; j > 0; --j) {
        a[j] = a[j - 1];
      }
      a[0] = temp;
    }
  }
}
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
/*  finds the single integer in the inclusive range 1...[len + 1] that does 
not appear in a. Because the elements of a are unique and all in the range
       1...(len + 1), there must be a single integer in that range
that is "missing" from a */
int missing(int a[], int len) { 
  for (int j = 1; j <= len + 1; ++j) {
    bool found = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
      if (a[i] == j) {
        found = true;
        break;
      }
    }
    if (!found) {
      return j;
    }
  }
  return -1;
}
```

Comment: If you truly care about efficiency then disassemble the optimized code and poke around there. "Big O" is mostly outdated since the number of iterations doesn't necessarily equal performance. Brute force linear search algorithms outperform binary search in many cases nowadays.

Comment: Easy way to find out: Test this code under various conditions of *N* like starting at 1 and going up by 10x each step. You'll very quickly discover the performance characteristics.

Comment: @Lundin It's probably homework/exercise for a theorical computer science class or something. That's not useful.

Comment: @tadman That won't help you to get a proof however...

Comment: @user202729 Not proof as in "what O notation does this have" but empirical data on how it performs on actual hardware. Usually the two correlate in a fashion where you can fit a curve to your points and it'll clearly resemble one of the major O functions.

Answer (score 2):

The first one has a worst-case time complexity of O(*n*<sup>2</sup>) (all even numbers, or at least a number of even numbers that scales with respect to *n*, such as random integers).  The effect of the if statement is that it improves the best-case time complexity (all odd numbers, so the if statement is always false and the inner loop never runs), which is O(*n*).  The inner loop itself is O(*n*) because the number of iterations still scales with *n*.

The second one is O(*n*<sup>2</sup>) in the worst case, because it scales with the length of the array and the missing number itself.  If the missing element were always 1, it would be O(*n*), because the outer loop would only run once.  Assuming the missing element is random, it's O(*n*<sup>2</sup>), because both loops would then scale with length.

Comment: Are you sure? Isn't `for(i=0; i<n; i++) for(j=i; j<n; j++)` O(n*log n)?

Comment: @klutt The inner loop runs from `1` to `n` times. The average number of iterations is thus `(1 + n) / 2`, or `n/2 + 0.5`.  That scales with `n`, not `log(n)`.

Comment: But hmmm, well when I think about it, it kind of looks like bubble sort

Comment: @klutt indeed, and bubble sort [has a time complexity of O(n^2)](https://www.studytonight.com/data-structures/bubble-sort)

Answer (score 1):

The effect of the if statement in the first function is that the second n in n^2 only applies for even numbers. The effect of the shorter loop is that it sort of halves the second n. If you look at the worst case, all evens, you get n * (n + 1) / 2, due to that shorter loop, which comes to O(n^2). The average case is still going to be O(n^2), though with close to a 1/4 factor.

Edit: After reading some comments I think I should add the best, worst and average case scenarios:

Best case, no evens, O(n)

Worst case, all evens, O(n * (n+1) / 2) = O(n^2)

Average case, half evens O(n * (n+1) / 4) (average result for half the evens works out to half the visits of the worst case) = O(n^2)

The break in the second function cuts the second n in n^2 to about half, so again, still O(n^2).

If you're trying to do better than O(n^2), I'm pretty sure you can solve both problems with O(n) if you just make an additional array, but you only asked what the effect of the if statement is and what the big O notation was.

Comment: You're correct about the if statement in the first, but the inner loop does not go through the whole array

Comment: It goes from the current i location to 1, so on average half, is what I calculated. That's why I said there was a 1/4 factor on average, about half the cases it goes into that second loop and about halfway on average through the list throughout the course of the loop. Maybe that's not precise, but I don't see how it multiplies the efficiency by anything other than a scalar on the average case, which means it's still O(n^2)

Comment: Loops on the form `for(i=0; i<n; i++) for(j=i; j<n; j++)` is O(n*log n) if I'm not mistaken

Comment: Well, I'm not sure. I'm leaving this. :)

Comment: Ok, looking at the worst case scenario, it's only just slightly worse than half of n^2 (that is, n(n+1)/2), so 1/4 is probably not correct. Regardless, I thought the whole point was kind of moot since both problems should be solvable with O(n) if you're allowed to use more memory.

Comment: That is definitely not O(n*log n). That's the classical (n * (n+1))/2 case, which is quadratic (O(n^2)). I'm pretty sure the original algorithm is still O(n^2), though not exactly (n^2)/4.

Comment: I edited the post to try to better reflect what you were saying.